# How do you write DRY, modular coffeescript with Sprockets in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets, javascript-namespaces

I'm in the early stages of trying to write some sensible Javascript. I want to namespace basically everything under the name of my application to avoid globals as much as possible, but still give me a way to access functions declared around the place. However, I don't want to be super verbose in my function definitions.

My ideal CoffeeScript would be something like this:

```
class @MyApp
  @myClassMethod = ->
    console.log 'This is MyApp.myClassMethod()'

  class @Module1
    @moduleMethod = ->
      console.log 'This is MyApp.Module1.moduleMethod()'
```

You get the picture. This way I avoid having to write `MyApp.Module.submoduleMethod = ->` every time I want to define a namespaced function properly - using `@` and defining things *within* my class definition keeps things nice and short.

This is all going well until I want to split my functionality up into multiple CoffeeScript files. Then what I really want is something like this:

```
// application.js
class @MyApp
  //= require 'module1'
  //= require 'module2'

// module1.js
class @Module1
  @moduleMethod = ->
    console.log 'This is STILL MyApp.Module1.moduleMethod()'
```

It doesn't seem like Sprockets can do this.

Is there a sensible way to require my CoffeeScript files in the right place in my container files? Or another way to approach writing modular code that is divided into separate files using CoffeeScript, Sprockets and Rails 3.1?

Comment: I think this question needs further investigation - the answers below aren't good enough, esp. since the creator of coffeescript has removed the "easy modules" page b/c the technique is poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a module solution that I use in my code.

I define my modules like below

```
@module "foo", ->
    @module "bar", ->
        class @Amazing
            toString: "ain't it"
```

Amazing is available as

```
foo.bar.Amazing
```

implementation of the @module helper is

```
window.module = (name, fn)->
  if not @[name]?
    this[name] = {}
  if not @[name].module?
    @[name].module = window.module
  fn.apply(this[name], [])
```

It's written up on the coffeescript website here.

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/Easy-modules-with-coffeescript

Comment: Thanks for the link. Any idea how to extend this so that it works nicely across multiple files?

Comment: It does work across multiple files. This is the whole point of it. What do you mean by nicely?

Comment: I meant without having to define all of the parent modules in each file. This may well be less annoying than I first thought though.

Comment: Where do you put the @module "foo", -> code? Can you put it in application.js? I thought it would need a .coffee extension...

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: The creator of coffeescript removed the link - he apparently thinks that it's not so good... so is there a proper way to organize JS files? For instance, I can't define constants or "instance variables" to be used throughout a "class" using the method that used to be given at the broken link...

Answer (score 4):

Simply keep module1.js as-is and make application.js look something like this:

```
//= require 'module1'

class @MyApp
  ...

  @Module1 = Module1
```

This will work because you've made `Module1` a global (declaring `class @Module1` is equivalent to writing `@Module1 = class Module1`, and `@` points to `window` in that context), and within the `class @MyApp` body, `@` points to the class itself.

If you want `Module1` to *only* be a property of the global `MyApp` class after it's attached, you could add the line

```
delete window.Module1
```

Comment: Good idea! There would still be a problem if my module names clashed with names in other scripts on the page, right? I'm being picky because I'm writing code that probably will be injected into other pages using a bookmarklet.

Comment: Ah, in that case I'd just define one global and then attach everything else to it. To do that, flip your dependency order around: In application.js, require `module1.js`, and in `module1.js`, require `myapp.js`, so that the global `MyApp` is defined first. You can then write `class MyApp.Module`...

Comment: My answer above handles the name collision problem. Using class is nice but it's not like in ruby where you can monkey patch. It will wipe out any previously define classes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815957/how-do-you-write-dry-modular-coffeescript-with-sprockets-in-rails-3-1/6826293#6826293 gets around this

Answer (score 1):

Here's the modular pattern I use for managing coffeescript with sprockets (works with Rails 4 as well):

```
  # utils.js.coffee

  class Utils
    constructor: ->

    foo: ->
      alert('bar!!!')

    # private methods should be prefixed with an underscore
    _privateFoo: ->
      alert('private methods should not be exposed')

  instance = new Utils()

  # only expose the methods you need to.
  # because this is outside of the class,
  # you can use coffee's sugar to define on window

  @utils = foo: instance.foo

  # otherscript.js.coffee 

  //= require utils
  class OtherScript
    constructor: ->
      @utils.foo()         # alerts bar!!!
      @utils._privateFoo() # undefined method error
```

One disadavantage of this approach is that you are exposing your objects on window. Adding a module loader or adopting some of the new es syntax around modules could be a nice alternative depending on your needs.